# how to use isin function in the IF condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use isin funtion in the if condtion within a function but it gives me an error

I have function `f` , and I am passing columns `A` from the dataframe `df` , and my if condition should check if A in `('IND','USA')` then return visited_countries else not_visited_countries

```
def f(A)
  if A.isin(['IND','USA']):
    return Visited_countries
  else:
    return not_visited_countries

df['D']=df.apply(lambda x: f(x.A,axis=1)
```

when I execute this code it give the below error

```
AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'isin'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: Is there a `isin()` function in python pandas?! i have never heard of it. Now, i learnt a new thing. Any ways, it's like `df['A'].isin(['IND','USA'])` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Series, not all DF, eg column A in DF so :
`if DF.A.isin(['IND','USA']).any():`

Comment: I am already passing the DF in my Lambda thats why I used A.isin without the DF , but still  tried your code it gives me a different error now "ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')"

Answer (score 2):

You may want this

```
df.loc[df.A.isin(['IND','USA']),'D'] = 'Visited_countries'
df.loc[~df.A.isin(['IND','USA']),'D'] = 'Not_visited_countries'
```

or you want to use if condition, I think you might use 'in' keyword. What about this?

```
df['D'] = df.A.apply(lambda x : 'Visited_countries' if x in ['IND','USA'] else 'Not_visited_countries')
```

Comment: I Have used this one before but , As I have other if and elif and else conditions I am using the function .

Comment: Here I have given sample code hence it will work , but in my real time code I have to use multiple if and else (nested ) conditions so it will become complex . That is the reason I have declared a function